# Unable to get pixi js elements after init

Tags: javascript, function, pixi.js

I need help form this bit of code, been stuck for hours, cant seems to figure out. Any help will be much appreciated.

I have multiple sections that has pixi.js app. Initiated the functions as below.

```
var pixiFunctions = [
    function(type) {

    var pixi, sectionContainer, stage, texture, sprite, bars;

    sectionContainer = $('section[data-media="established"]');

    var established = {
        init: function() {

            pixi = new PIXI.Application({
                width: getViewport().width,
                height: getViewport().height,
                transparent: true,
                resolution: window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
                antialias: true
            });

            sectionContainer.append(pixi.view);
            stage = new PIXI.Container();
            texture = new PIXI.Texture.from(loadedMedia[1].src);
            texture.baseTexture.resource.autoplay = false;
            texture.baseTexture.resource.source.loop = 'loop';

            sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);

            texture.baseTexture.on('loaded', function() {

                sprite.height = pixi.renderer.screen.height;
                sprite.width = pixi.renderer.screen.width;

                pixi.stage.addChild(sprite);
                established.start();
            });


        },

        start: function() {
            pixi.render(stage);
            requestAnimationFrame(established.start);
        },

        animateIn: function() {
            console.log('animateIN');
            **console.log(pixi)**
            sectionContainer.addClass('active');
        },

        animateOut: function() {
            console.log('animateOut');

            sectionContainer.removeClass('active');
        }
    }

    if (type === 'animateIn') established.animateIn();
    if (type === 'animateOut') established.animateOut();
    if (type === 'init') established.init();
}
]
```

I have a sets of functions like this for each ,
On DOM load, I am calling these functions in this manner,

```
for (var i = 0; i < pixiFunctions.length; i++) {

    pixiFunctions[i]('init');

}
```

And here comes the issue, when I am scrolling, I have set up functions to fire up in this manner;

```
 pixiFunctions[currentPosition]('animateIn');
```

[currentPosition] - refers to the count that increment as you scroll so that I can animate in sections.

Issue is whenever i call this function with a , the console logs as PIXI undefined. I have no clue how to sort it out. I needed this because I need to get a hold of pixi in order to animate the  mask.

** pixiFunctionscurrentPosition;**

Thank you all.

Comment: did you call the function when the dom was ready?

Comment: Yeah, apparently the variable (`var pixi, sectionContainer, stage, texture, sprite, bars;`) are not updated on the by the init function. I made it that way because I can reference it later. But declaring it above this function will work but will be ugly because then I would have `pixi1, sectionContainer1`. Is there a better solution. Thanks a lot, appreciate it